# how to analyse the keyword with custom analyzer in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I have a test case in lucene  like {"UK" [Brixit]}, during this search I have multi keyword like UK and Brixit. which I like to analyze with separate analyzer like "UK"  with no-stemming and no-casesensitive and with Brixit I want to analyse the brixit with stemming. so that keyword like UK and Brixit should match with all case. and based on that I like to search this keyword on lucene.

Comment: you can apply the custom analyzer but have to see how to parse the symbol like [ and ] with { and } . you should write the code to parse the keyword like this.

Comment: Nitpick: don't you mean brexit instead of brixit?

Comment: did I get you correct - you want to apply different analyzers, depends on the word/token?

Comment: yes but how to do that I have no idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper[[JavaDoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html)]
where you define for which field you like to use which analyzer.
And for each Field you can use a CustomAnalyzer [[JavaDoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/custom/CustomAnalyzer.html)] which you define how you like it to be analyzed.

Comment: can you have any code for that implementation. and what about { this.

Comment: do you need this special characters? i would recommend removing special characters and extract the values to put them in different fields.

Comment: no i need to to use this symbol for special purpose. suppose I want a text to use as multikeyword or simple keyword such as CEO of Microsoft, and Ministry of Defence both have same pattern but analysis would be different.  and based on analysis I want to apply analyser. hope I am making sense.